# workaround for multiple ** parameters are not allowed

Tags: python

I have functions foo1 and foo2, which I would like to use via **kwargs. However, if I separate them into **kwargs_for_a and **kwargs_for_b, it is not allowed and if I use a single **kwargs, the  final b2=30 will throw an error in foo1 since foo1 does not have any parameter called b2. How could I get this working?

```
def foo1(a1, a2=3, a3=4):
    return a1 + a2 + a3


def foo2(b1, b2=3):
    return b1 + b2


def main(a1, b1, **kwargs_for_a, **kwargs_for_b):
    return foo1(a1, **kwargs_for_a) + foo2(b1, **kwargs_for_b)


main(2, 3, a2=10, b2=30)
```

Comment: I would typically write `def foo1(a1, a2=3, a3=4, **kwargs)`, and likewise for `foo2()`.  That tells `foo1` to wrap up the arguments it doesn't understand, and then you can ignore them.  I might even use `_kwargs` to emphasize that I don't care about them.

Comment: How would having more than one `**kwargs` work at all? There's only one set of "here are all the keyword arguments". How is `main` supposed to know, if you pass `a2=10, b2=30, c2=40` which kwargs dict each parameter goes into?

Comment: When you're calling `main()`, how would it know which keywords should be put in each dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't.** Keep your kwargs as separate dicts for as long as there's a need to distinguish.

```
def main(a1, b1, kwargs_for_a, kwargs_for_b):
    return foo1(a1, **kwargs_for_a) + foo2(b1, **kwargs_for_b)


main(2, 3, dict(a2=10), dict(b2=30))
```

Remember, `**kwargs` gets *all* the keyword arguments that are left -- not just one of them. There only exists one "all the keyword arguments" set.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice, but just for fun.

Here is an approach that tries to use all the provided kwargs on `foo1`, detects which ones are not unexpected, rejects them and use them in `foo2`.

```py
def foo1(a1, a2=3, a3=4):
    return a1 + a2 + a3


def foo2(b1, b2=3):
    return b1 + b2


def main(a1, b1, **kwargs):
    
    rejected_kwargs = {}
    while True:
        try:
            r1 = foo1(a1, **kwargs)
            break
        except TypeError as e:
            message = "foo1() got an unexpected keyword argument "
            if not str(e).startswith(message):
                raise e
            else:
                key = str(e).split(message)[1].strip("'")
                rejected_kwargs[key] = kwargs.pop(key) # Here, `b2` was rejected by `foo1` and is now available for `foo2`. 
        
    r2 = foo2(b1, **rejected_kwargs)
    
    return r1 + r2


main(2, 3, a2=10, b2=30)
```